# Bubble Sort Time C program

Tags: linux, gcc, bubble-sort

The test is to create an array of size 10000. Initialize it with the values 10000 down to 1 and then use a bubble sort to reverse the order.As a bubble sort is one of the worst possible sorts, this should take a fairly long time. However, the resolution of the timing is limited.

The solution is to put the task inside a loop that repeats it a thousand or a million times—whatever it takes to get the numbers up to something you can deal with. I am getting errors in my code. Please see my code below.

The following commands are run on linux:
*gcc -o sort sort.c -O2

time ./sort*

*gcc -m32 -o sort sort.c -O2 -march=pentium4

time ./sort*

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bubbleSort(int numbers[], int array_size)
{

    int i, j, temp;

    for (i =0; i <array_size; i++)
    {
        for (j =0; j<array_size-1; j++)
        {
            if (numbers[j] > numbers[j+1])  {
                temp = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = numbers[j+1];
                numbers[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[10000];
    int i;

    for(i=10000;i!=0;i--)
    {
        array[i-1]=i;
    }
    bubbleSort(array,10000);
    for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code? Compiles fine, runs quadratically, as expected.

Comment: What errors are you getting? looks ok to me.

Comment: Kindly post your `errors`, so that we can try to find out the better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code stores the numbers in the array in ascending order.

```
    for(i=10000;i!=0;i--)
    {
        array[i-1]=i;
    }
```

Your sorting algorithm also sorts the numbers in ascending order, so you won't find any change to the numbers in the array.

```
        if (numbers[j] > numbers[j+1])  
        {
            temp = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = numbers[j+1];
            numbers[j+1] = temp;
        }
```

Change the above if as follows,

```
        if (numbers[j] < numbers[j+1]) 
        {
            temp = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = numbers[j+1];
            numbers[j+1] = temp;
        }
```

Comment: As mentioned in my answer the sorting order might be a problem. Please check it.

Comment: yes i did change that according to your if statement. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
void bubbleSort(int numbers[], int array_size)
{
   int i, j, temp;
   for (i =0; i <array_size-1; i++)
   {
       for (j =0; j<array_size - i -1; j++)
       {
        if (numbers[j] > numbers[j+1])  
           {
               temp = numbers[j];
               numbers[j] = numbers[j+1];
               numbers[j+1] = temp;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I need to declare the array size.

Comment: i also want to run the profiling method                           gcc -o sort sort.c -pg -O2 -march=pentium2 
$ ./sort 
$ gprof --no-graph -b ./sort gmon.out 
time seconds    seconds calls ms/call ms/call name 
100.00 0.79        0.79       1      790.00 790.00 bubbleSort 
0.00     0.79        0.00       1      0.00     0.00     init_list 
it should give me the above values, but i get error gmon.out no such file

Comment: I don't think so. since we are passing argument as value to array_size, there is no need. And, I tried both, your code is also working fine, there are no errors.

Comment: By the way, using that "time ./a.out" command displays o/p with three different times: real, sys, user. 
I don,t have any idea regarding these. I think there should be single time, specifying amount of time required by program.